# How can I group by two fields and count each type of data by date occurrence?

Tags: r

I have a dataset (first 100 rows):

```
structure(list(department = structure(c(21L, 14L, 4L, 11L, 21L, 
12L, 15L, 11L, 3L, 18L, 4L, 20L, 25L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 19L, 22L, 
18L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 20L, 12L, 4L, 27L, 1L, 6L, 16L, 
1L, 13L, 13L, 25L, 18L, 8L, 23L, 10L, 16L, 4L, 21L, 2L, 5L, 18L, 
10L, 23L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 14L, 15L, 19L, 23L, 11L, 4L, 15L, 6L, 12L, 
11L, 23L, 14L, 15L, 11L, 18L, 24L, 27L, 27L, 20L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 
4L, 10L, 4L, 26L, 3L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 22L, 14L, 20L, 25L, 2L, 
23L, 15L, 13L, 4L, 18L, 26L, 13L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 22L, 
5L, 14L), .Label = c("Beauty", "Boutique advisor", "Boutique advisors", 
"Boutique Stylist", "Clean Beauty Expert", "Conseiller en boutique", 
"Design Consultant", "Designer Trade Specialist", "Food", "Furniture", 
"In-store Design Expert", "In-store experts", "In-Store Sales Professional", 
"In-Store Style Experts", "John Hardy", "Jos. A. Bank LIVE!", 
"Levi's Stylists", "Lighting & Home Accessories", "Men's Wearhouse LIVE!", 
"Menswear", "Personal advisors", "Styliste en boutique", "Vendeurs", 
"Wine", "Women's Accessories", "Women's shoes", "Womenswear"), class = "factor"), 
    type = c("Completed", "Missed", "Missed", "Missed", "Missed", 
    "Missed", "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Missed", 
    "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", 
    "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", 
    "Missed", "Completed", "Missed", "Missed", "Completed", "Missed", 
    "Missed", "Missed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Missed", 
    "Completed", "Missed", "Missed", "Completed", "Missed", "Missed", 
    "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Missed", 
    "Completed", "Missed", "Missed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", 
    "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", 
    "Completed", "Missed", "Missed", "Missed", "Missed", "Completed", 
    "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", 
    "Missed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", 
    "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Missed", "Completed", 
    "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", 
    "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", 
    "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", 
    "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", 
    "Completed", "Missed", "Completed"), date = structure(c(17889, 
    17890, 17893, 17893, 17892, 17892, 17893, 17893, 17892, 17888, 
    17892, 17889, 17888, 17893, 17888, 17889, 17891, 17892, 17893, 
    17891, 17889, 17888, 17892, 17889, 17889, 17892, 17888, 17889, 
    17893, 17892, 17893, 17892, 17891, 17893, 17888, 17891, 17892, 
    17891, 17892, 17888, 17891, 17893, 17893, 17892, 17890, 17888, 
    17888, 17889, 17891, 17893, 17893, 17890, 17890, 17892, 17889, 
    17892, 17889, 17889, 17888, 17888, 17893, 17893, 17893, 17891, 
    17888, 17892, 17892, 17893, 17891, 17888, 17889, 17891, 17889, 
    17890, 17891, 17888, 17889, 17888, 17890, 17893, 17889, 17889, 
    17893, 17889, 17892, 17891, 17889, 17892, 17888, 17891, 17893, 
    17890, 17890, 17889, 17893, 17889, 17889, 17888, 17889, 17892
    ), class = "Date"), count = c(7L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    10L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 18L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 17L, 277L, 10L, 14L, 50L, 
    520L, 92L, 791L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 145L, 17L, 10L, 
    42L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 627L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 20L, 41L, 4L, 283L, 1L, 14L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    7L, 12L, 36L, 9L, 14L, 1L, 6L, 13L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 16L, 3L, 
    2L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 21L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 22L, 12L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 23L, 
    36L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 32L)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need it to look like this (grouped by department (rows) and a respective count of each type per day (columns)):

[image]

At present, I have two approaches to this, neither of which quite produce the desired outcome but I suspect that I am close because the solution appears to lie somewhere between the two.

First approach:

```
library(dplyr) # For the purpose of this reproducible example should you need it

dept %>%
group_by(
    department
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    missed = sum(type == "Missed"),
    completed = sum(type == "Completed"),
    missed_pct = missed / (missed + completed)
  )
```

Which gives me this:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  department          missed completed missed_pct
  <fct>                <int>     <int>      <dbl>
1 Beauty                   2         5      0.286
2 Food                     0         1      0    
3 Menswear                 4         6      0.4  
4 Wine                     1         1      0.5  
5 Women's Accessories      2         5      0.286
6 Women's shoes            3         5      0.375
7 Womenswear               4         5      0.444
```

Second approach:

```
library(dplyr) # For the purpose of this reproducible example should you need it

dept %>%
  group_by(
    department,
    date
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    missed = sum(type == "Missed"),
    completed = sum(type == "Completed"),
    missed_pct = missed / (missed + completed)
  )
```

Which gives me this:

```
# A tibble: 28 x 5
# Groups:   department [?]
   department date       missed completed missed_pct
   <fct>      <date>      <int>     <int>      <dbl>
 1 Beauty     2018-12-23      0         1        0  
 2 Beauty     2018-12-24      0         1        0  
 3 Beauty     2018-12-26      0         1        0  
 4 Beauty     2018-12-27      1         1        0.5
 5 Beauty     2018-12-28      1         1        0.5
 6 Food       2018-12-27      0         1        0  
 7 Menswear   2018-12-23      1         1        0.5
 8 Menswear   2018-12-24      1         1        0.5
 9 Menswear   2018-12-25      0         1        0  
10 Menswear   2018-12-26      1         1        0.5
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hey, there is a pair of duplicate observations in the 48th and 73rd rows. How to deat with it ? Add them together or delete the last one ?

Comment: Good spot, but they aren't actually duplicates in real life. They only appear to be duplicates because the full dataset contains a column with confidential client details, thus making them unique - I have just removed the details before sharing the data is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grouping, you need to reshape your data from long to wide format. This is called 'casting'.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dept, department + type ~ date, fun.aggregate = sum)
```

Which gives:

```
         department      type 2018-12-23 2018-12-24 2018-12-25 2018-12-26 2018-12-27 2018-12-28
1            Beauty Completed          0         12          0          0         17          6
2            Beauty    Missed          0          0          0          0          0          3
3  Boutique advisor Completed          0          0          0          0          1          4
4 Boutique advisors Completed          1          4          0          0          1          7
5  Boutique Stylist Completed         13          5          0          3          5          0
6  Boutique Stylist    Missed          2          6          0          6          5          8
```

Your image also shows a % row. Do you need this?

Edit: To add the percent rows, calculate them before reshaping:

```
dept %>%
# create the percentage rows by grouping by department/date/type. Later we will combine these rows back with the original data
group_by(department, date, type) %>%
# add a column n with the sum of count in each group
summarise(n=sum(count)) %>%
# do 2 separate things:
#   - add a percent column
#   - change all the values in the type column to have a % at the end so they don't get mixed up with the original values later
mutate(percent = n * 100 / sum(n), type = paste(type, "%")) %>%
# remove all rows except the percent ones
filter(type == "Missed %") %>%
# remove the temporary 'n' column we created earlier, and rename the percent column to 'count' so it can go through the 'dcast' function later without any problems
select(department, type, count = percent, "date") %>%
# append with the original data
bind_rows(dept) %>%
# cast the data with the date column used as columns
# and fill it with the sum of the 'count' column
# the percentage rows we created earlier will pass through the function unharmed as there is only one of them in each department/type/date
dcast(department + type ~ date, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "count")
```

Which gives:

```
         department      type 2018-12-23 2018-12-24 2018-12-25 2018-12-26 2018-12-27 2018-12-28
1            Beauty Completed          0         12          0          0         17    6.00000
2            Beauty    Missed          0          0          0          0          0    3.00000
3            Beauty  Missed %          0          0          0          0          0   33.33333
4  Boutique advisor Completed          0          0          0          0          1    4.00000
5 Boutique advisors Completed          1          4          0          0          1    7.00000
6  Boutique Stylist Completed         13          5          0          3          5    0.00000
```

Comment: This looks good and yes, the percentage rows are very important.

Comment: How can I add the percentage calculation back in with your solution?

Comment: This seems perfect, although the `%` symbol isn't showing up (in the `mutate()` portion) in my final results - why might this be?

Comment: Do you mean that none of the values in the `type` column contain a trailing % sign?

Comment: Or do you want the actual values to be formatted so each has a percent sign? (Currently they are numeric)

Comment: I'm referring to this line: `mutate(percent = round(n * 100 / sum(n), 2), type = paste(type, "%"))`. I thought the purpose of `...paste(type, "%")...` was to add a `%` to each of the calculated percentages.

Comment: It was to add a '%' to the names in the type column

Comment: I see. I find that confusing (especially the `mutate()` portion) - would you mind adding commentary to each line of your solution so that I know precisely what is happening at each stage?

Comment: Comments added in answer

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.  Chosen answer and duly upvoted for the extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
dept %>%
  group_by(department, date, type) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(count, na.rm = T)) %>%   # data had a few duplicate rows
  spread(type, count, fill = 0) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(department, date) %>% 
  mutate(missed_pct = Missed / (Missed + Completed)) %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("department", "date")) %>% 
  spread(date, value) %>% 
  rename(type = variable)
```

Let me know if you would like any of this explained. Essentially just multiple uses of spread and melt to ensure the data is structured as we want it at each stage (I would suggest running up to each melt/spread and note how the data.frame is shaped.)

Comment: I have a question: why do you use `as.data.frame()` twice?  I tried it with both present, with one present and with no `as.data.frame()`s present and the results look identical every time.

Comment: Its just a habit (possibly a bad one). I will remove the second one as it is not needed. The first is not needed in this case as you first `group_by(department, date, type)` and later `group_by(department, date)` which is allowed. If however we performed these group_bys in the other order we would hit an error. This is because the groupings are held onto and its impossible to add a grouping variable. `as.data.frame()` removes the grouping variables and lets you group by another set of variables.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining.  anotherfred's answer works better in my particular case however, but I have duly upvoted for the effort.